# Windows 10 S3 shutdown

Tags: windows, shutdown, wake-on-lan

I am trying to figure out why my Windows 10's regular shutdown button does not let me WOL my PC.

Before my upgrade from 8.1 i was using a small file which ran a command prompt S3 shutdown. 
Which still works, but i am trying to get it to work with the regular windows 10 shutdown button.

My Bios and NIC settings are all set correct.
Yet only the command prompt shutdown allows me to use WOL.
Command used Shutdown /s /t 0

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Fast Boot:

1. Press `WIN+R`
2. Type `regedit`
3. Press `ENTER`
4. Change the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power\HiberbootEnabled` to 0